# HTML in an <option> of <select size="?" list compiled by Angular not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, angular, rendering

I have a simple Angular component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `Hello!`,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
}
```

I want to display in a `<select>` list

```
<select size="2">
  <option value="1">
    <hello></hello>
  </option>
</select>
```

Output:
[image]
It is selectable and in the DOM but blank.

If I remove `size="2"` it works perfectly, but I want a list not a drop down.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

As @PoulKruijt commented this is not limited to Angular components, any HTML `<element>` will not render in Chromium-based browsers when a `<select>` has a `size` when using Angular.

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered a bug in chrome :D Try it in Edge, and it works. Go to inspect change the tag manually from hello to `div` and you will see it works. So somehow the rendering engine of chrome is messing it up

Comment: It's not even an issue with being a nested component, anything except a text node doesn't show [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ukazcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @PoulKruijt Thanks!, so this question is totally mislabeled should I delete it? Also, is this bug documented somewhere? Googling takes me down the rabbit hole.

Comment: I've also searched for similar issues, but haven't been able to find a single one. If I were you I would file a bug on the angular github. It could be that it can be fixed by them, or at least they can figure out if it's an angular bug or a chrome bug. About this question, you can rename it to reflect that any html inside a select with specified `size` does not render in chrome, and attach your bug report for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a bug report with [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37295) which was closed within 15 minutes with the following explanation:

> tag is invalid as a child of  element, see: [Problem with <h1> in drop down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572755)
>
> If you compare DOM of the "working" example you will notice that  is not there as HTML parser removed it. Angular creates elements through the DOM API so a HTML parser couldn't do the auto-corrections for you.
>
> Still, the bottom line is that you've got invalid HTML.

Context: the *working* example is plain HTML that I wrote part of the bug report. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-ue9hrn?embed=1&file=src/index.html